# Modal Form Login aparece uma vez e some no mesmo instante

Tags: javascript, css, formulário, login, modal

Estou com um probleminha aqui com esse modal form. O JS funciona certinho, porém a janela modal aparece e some rapidamente. Como solucionar?

```
<a href="" id="signin"><li>Entrar</li></a></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<!--modal-->
<div class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span class="close" title="sair">&times;</span>
            <img src="img/users.png" alt="users" class="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="uname"><b>E-mail</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Entre com o seu e-mail" required>
            <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
            <input type="password" name="psw" placeholder="insira sua senha">
            <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lembrar" checked="checked">Lembre-ne
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="container"style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
            <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancelar</button>
            <span class="psw">Esqueceu a <a href="">senha?</a></span>
        </div>
    </form>

<script>
    document.getElementById("signin").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
});

document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "none";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Certíssimo !

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não faz sentido algum você colocar um elemento `<li>` dentro de um elemento `<a>`:

```
<a href="" id="signin"><li>Entrar</li></a>
```

Isso não é permitido pelos padrões da W3C e WHATWG. O correto seria inverter os elementos:

```
<li><a href="" id="signin">Entrar</a></li>
```

Segundo, o problema de exibir brevemente o modal é devido ao seu link "entrar". Como você não definir um valor em `href`, por padrão, ele apontará para a própria URL e, quando clicado, a página é recarregada. As suas opções são:

1. Definir o valor de `href` como `href="#!"`, pois assim o navegador tentará redirecionar o usuário para o elemento cujo `id="!"` e, como provavelmente não existirá, naca acontecerá.
2. Definir o valor de `href` como `href="javascript:void()"`, tendo o mesmo efeito que o item anterior; ou
3. Utilizar o `preventDefault()` do evento `click` no seu elemento:

   ```
   document.getElementById("signin").addEventListener("click", function(event){
       document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
       event.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

Desta forma, você informa ao usuário que não deseja o comportamento normal do clique em uma âncora e o usuário não será redirecionado.

Leituras adicionais:

- [Atributo "href" para links em JavaScript: "#" ou "javascript:void(0)"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/773/5878)
- [Qual a diferença de uso de return false, event.stopPropagation() e event.preventDefault()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167/5878)
- [Como impedir um click sobre um link/âncora ou elemento com evento amarrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2352/5878)
- [Qual a finalidade do comando "return true;" no final de uma função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89889/5878)
- [Por que "return false;" , em um evento de clique, cancela a abertura do link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51257/5878)

Answer (score -1):

Eu tava com mesmo problema.
No caso eu tinha um botão que acionava o modal.
Só que antes do botão tinha um link que cobria o botão ai não pegava, tireo o link e dó deixei o botão veja como tava.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]